# If I declare a class instance on the heap are all its members going to be on the heap as well?

Tags: c++, object, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I was wondering if I declare a class instance on the heap (new) are its members going to be on the heap as well even if they weren’t created using the new keyword?

Comment: Yes?  How could they possibly end up on the stack?  Do you have an example of something you think might end up stacked?  (Also, I'm not the downvoter.)  PS - the constructor and functions will use the stack for local variables but those are not member variables.

Comment: All the data in a class instance is contiguous in memory. It's just one object.

Comment: However, if a class contains pointers, those pointers can point to the stack or static data.

Comment: The only way they won't be for sure is if the class is declared to have no members. Non-existent member won't be on the heap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say that we declare a class like so:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::string Bar;
public:
    Foo(std::string Bar);
}
```

When you create a new object of that class, it's data members are saved **on the same place as the object itself**, meaning that if you do something like this `Foo* f = new Foo("hello");` all of the data is stored in the heap, but if you do `Foo f = Foo("hello");` it will be stored on the stack.

Why so? when you create an object of class like `foo`, it's data members are referred as `sub-objects`, and from the memory's perspective, the class object and it's sub-objects are one, meaning that if you create an object of `foo` on the heap, all of it's sub-objects will be stored on the heap as well as they are one with the class object itself. When you create an instance of a class, you don't get redirected to somewhere else when you try to access it's data members, you merely accessing a specific part within the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes all member variables inside your class are continuous in memory. So if your class object is in heap (created with new) the object will use the memory up to sizeof(YourClass). The size depends on the individual size of all its non static members (some padding might be applied too).

```
class ExampleClass {
public:
    int first;
    float second;
};

void test() {
    ExampleClass *obj = new ExampleClass;

    std::cout << obj << " object address \n";
    std::cout << &obj->first << " first member address \n";
    std::cout << &obj->second << " second member address \n";

    delete obj;
}

Will print:
0x55c0f4c85eb0 object address
0x55c0f4c85eb0 first member address
0x55c0f4c85eb4 second member address
```

Comment: `[...]object is in heap (created with new)[...]` you need to be careful with such statements. First of all, there is also [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) that allows to create an object using `new` on the stack. And you can overload the `new` and `delete`operator for a class. `new` says something about [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). While objects with _dynamic_ storage duration normally exist in the heap, it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you take in account the [docs](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#layout-obj):

> Like C, C++ doesn’t define layouts, just semantic constraints that must be met. Therefore different implementations do things differently.

But commonly, there is a layout and objects aren't split in different memory regions (except functions), so it will go together to heap or stack (heap in your case.)

> Object representation
>
> For an object of type `T`, object representation is the sequence of `sizeof(T)` objects of type `unsigned char` (or, equivalently, `std::byte`) beginning at the same address as the `T` object.